# Trouble implementing Perlin noise in python

Tags: python, interpolation, noise

I'm attempting to implement the algorithm for generating 2D Perlin noise [here](http://webstaff.itn.liu.se/~stegu/TNM022-2005/perlinnoiselinks/perlin-noise-math-faq.html) but I'm having some trouble doing it in Python (which I am relatively new to).

I was expecting the final noise values ('z' in the linked example), to be somewhere between 0.0 and 1.0, but that's not what I'm getting. My code is below, I'd really appreciate any input.

Thanks!

perlin.py:

```
import math
import numpy
import random
import vector as vctr

from PIL import Image


def dot(v1, v2):
    """
    Returns the dot product of the two input vectors.

    Args:
    v1 - First vector
    v2 - Second vector

    Return:
    Resulting dot product
    """
    return (v1.x * v2.x) + (v1.y * v2.y)


def fade(t):
    """
    Fade 3t^2 - 2t^3

    Args:
    t  - Value to fade.

    Return:
    Faded value.
    """
    return (3 * (t ** 2)) - (2 * (t ** 3))


def lerp(minVal, maxVal, term):
    """
    Args:

    Return:
    """
    return (maxVal - minVal) * term + minVal


def generateImage(noises, file="perlin.png"):
    """
    Generates a image on disc of the resulting noise values

    Args:
    noises (list) - 2d list of noise values
    file (str) - location of file to write to
    """
    pixels = numpy.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype=numpy.uint8)

    for x in range(0, width):
        for y in range(0, height):  
            rgb = 255 * noises[x][y]
            pixels[x, y] = [rgb, rgb, rgb]

    # Print pixels as image    
    img = Image.fromarray(pixels, 'RGB')
    img.save(file)

# Define the noise region
width  = 300
height = 300

# Column ordered array of generated gradient vectors
g = numpy.zeros((width + 1, height + 1)).tolist()

# List of final noise values
z = numpy.zeros((width, height)).tolist()


# Fill list with randomly directed unit vectors (one for each grid point)
for x in range(0, width + 1):
    for y in range(0, height + 1):
        randX = random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0)
        randY = random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0)
        length = math.sqrt(randX**2 + randY**2)
        g[x][y] = vctr.vector(randX / length, randY / length)


# For each cell in the sampling space (i.e. each pixel)
for x in range(0, width):
    for y in range(0, height):

        # Generate random point (p) within and relative to current cell
        pX = random.uniform(0.0, 1.0)
        pY = random.uniform(0.0, 1.0)

        # Get the gradient vectors for each cell corner
        g_tl = g[x][y]
        g_tr = g[x + 1][y]
        g_bl = g[x][y + 1]
        g_br = g[x + 1][y + 1]

        # Vectors from each cell corner to the generated point
        # X axis is positive going right, Y is positive going down
        tl = vctr.vector(pX, pY)
        tr = vctr.vector(pX - 1, pY)
        bl = vctr.vector(pX, pY - 1)
        br = vctr.vector(pX - 1, pY - 1)

        # Dot product these vectors to get gradient values
        u = dot(tl, g_tl)
        v = dot(tr, g_tr)
        s = dot(bl, g_bl)
        t = dot(br, g_br)

        # Interpolate the gradient values
        sX = fade(pX)
        sY = fade(pY)

        a = s + (sX * (t - s))
        b = u + (sX * (v - u))
        value = a + (sY * (a - b))

        if (value < 0.0) or (value > 1.0):
            print("VALUE IS OUT OF BOUNDS??? " + str(value))

        z[x][y] = value


generateImage(z)
print("Completed Perlin noise generation!")
```

vector.py:

```
class vector:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """
        Initialise a new vector in 2D space with the input X and Y values.

        x: X value of vector
        y: Y value of vector
        """
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Comment: Can we get what it puts out? "It doesn't give proper output" could be a hundred different reasons.

Comment: It currently outputs the image here (http://imgur.com/J46SzZU) but in doing so generates a large number of values < 0.0 and > 1.0

Comment: Well, your math doesn't seem to guarantee values such that `0.0 < value < 1.0` - `fade()` seems to increase the value for randoms >0.5 (may be intended, just seems awkward) and addition is a very good place to look at for going out of bounds- check what a, b, s, and u are- I think they're probably the key (since multiplication of <1 numbers will always be <1, but addition can easily go out of bounds)